# Script that hides Wordpress comment count doesn't work with Disqus

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, disqus

I'd like to hide the wordpress comment count if there are no comments on the specific post.

```
<?php 
  if (have_comments()) { 
    echo comments_number('');
  } else {
    echo ' ';
  } 
?>
```

This works fine with the standard Wordpress comments but doesn't work when Disqus is installed.

Does anybody know a work around?

Answer (score 2):

The Disqus plugin for Wordpress automatically generates a comment count that replaces the default Wordpress comment count. In your Disqus admin settings here http://disqus.com/admin/settings/, you can specify different comment count text for 0 comments, 1 comment, and multiple comments, shown here: [image: Comment Count Link text] Edit the 'Zero Comments' feild to be blank so that the comment count will not appear when there are 0 comments. It is not necessary to edit the Disqus plugin.

Comment: Hi Dmatt, I need the entire comment block to be hidden if there are no comments though. This includes the surrounding <div> not just the comment count. This is easy with the standard Wordpress comments as I just use the script above. But Disqus doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your able to edit the plugin. DISQUS controls all of their plugin files, so you unable to edit them.

I hope this helps, sorry if I gave bad answer.

Comment: That would be rather sucky if so... :( Cheers Tyree

Comment: The person above gave a better answer. So I would his answer, sorry for not being too knowledgeable about this=)